# How to display a variable as checkbox in visual force page?

Tags: visualforce

I'm trying to read an integer value from the controller and render it as a checkbox in my Visual force page. If 1 render it as checked and if 0 render it as unchecked. I get a compilation error *Unknown property 'readValue'*. If I simply did a apex:inputcheckbox selected="true" it doesn't work either.

```
    <apex:datatable value="{!classRows}" var="class" id="classTable"
        <apex:inputhidden value="{!class[column01.FieldName]}" id="hvl01" rendered="true" />
        <apex:variable var="readValue" value="{!IF(class[column01.FieldName]=1,true,false)}" id="testread" />
        <apex:outputtext value="{!readValue}" />
        <apex:inputcheckbox selected="{!readValue}" id="chk01" />
     </apex:datatable>
```

Comment: Do you have a public Boolean attribute in your controller called `readValue`? i.e: `public Boolean readValue {get;set;}` Also you need to set the merge field as the value in the input checkbox `<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!readValue}">`

Comment: @Ranga Thank you so much! I added the ReadValue getter setter in the controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that you have a boolean attribute defined in your controller named `readValue`.

**Controller:**

```
...
public Boolean readValue {get;set;}
...
```

Also in your page set the value of the input checkbox as follows:

**Page:**

```
...
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!readValue}">
...
```